# Replace null array value from array in php

Tags: php

I run a query and got id values in an array. Then I push those id like this `array_push($id);` then I implode ',' into an array and place it in a variable like this  `$val = implode(",",$id);`. When I output it i get following result
`,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`. Problem in this result is that first value is ',' and it is because first record that I am getting from database is giving me Null value. I want to remove `','` from first place if first record is empty. So that desire result should be `2,3,4,5,6,7,8`.

Please anybody can help me how can I remove ',' from first place. Or any suggestion to solve this problem

Comment: Perhaps, if you retrieve array from the db, you can put `WHERE id IS NOT NULL` in your SQL query.

Comment: There are several things you can do to "make the nulls go away", such as using `array_filter` as Baba mentions (btw, you **must** provide a custom callback to distinguish `null` from `0`). But is making them go away the correct thing to do? That depends on your business rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$id = array_filter($id, 'ord'); // removes 0 length values, or
$id = array_filter($id, 'strlen'); // same as above but a bit slower, or
$id = array_filter($id, 'count'); // removes only NULL values and empty arrays

$val = implode(",",$id);
```

You might also want to consider using `is_numeric` as the `array_filter` callback.

Doing just `array_filter($id)` will remove *falsy* (like `0`) elements that you might want.

Comment: Note that `is_numeric` returns true for strings like `'10e5'` (because it could be scientific notation) which is often not what you want. `ctype_digit` is generally more appropriate, but will complain if its input is not a string.

Comment: @IMSoP: Yes, and `is_int` complains if it's not a integer. But I guess in this case everything is a string.